Bad Request and Invalid HTTP_HOST header in deployment NGINX + Gunicorn + Django?
Could you, please, help me with some suggestion where or how to find a resolution of my DisallowedHost exception?
I have deployed my Django project to the DigitalOcean Ubuntu server with Nginx + Gunicorn according to instructions from DjangoProject and DigitalOcean as well as answers from related questions from DjangoForum, StackOverflow and others. I believe I tried all the advice I could find but still have 400 BadRequest responses, and Invalid HTTP_HOST header Error.
likarnet is my project name, and likarnet.com is my domain.
I have connected domain likarnet.com to my public IP and SSL certificate to my domain.
Versions python 3.12, django 5.0.6
Please, excuse me if I ask some obvious things. This is my first project.
File /etc/nginx/sites-available/likarnet
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name likarnet.com www.likarnet.com;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
            root /home/likarnet/website/likarnet;
        }

        location /media/ {
            root /home/likarnet/website/likarnet;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        }
}

I have just tried to use default include proxy_params;
File /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=likarnet
Group=sudo
WorkingDirectory=/home/likarnet/website/likarnet
ExecStart=/home/likarnet/venv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          --chdir=/home/likarnet/website/likarnet \
          likarnet.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

So, when I run project with python3 manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000 or 0.0.0.0:8000 and try from another terminal curl -v localhost:8000 I get
* Host localhost:8000 was resolved.
* IPv6: ::1
* IPv4: 127.0.0.1
*   Trying [::1]:8000...
* connect to ::1 port 8000 from ::1 port 59232 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8000...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8000
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8000
> User-Agent: curl/8.5.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Fri, 21 Jun 2024 21:43:57 GMT
< Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.12.3
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Location: https://localhost:8000/
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Referrer-Policy: same-origin
< Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
< Connection: close
< 
* Closing connection

And in terminal with project I got additional rows Host, ALLOWED_HOSTS, Domain and Port as I added printing them into function get_host() in /venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/http/request.py
Host:  localhost:8000
ALLOWED_HOSTS:  ['likarnet.com', '.likarnet.com', '64.225.77.248', '127.0.0.1', 'localhost']
Domain:  localhost
Port:  8000
[21/Jun/2024 21:51:17] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 0

When I try curl --unix-socket /run/gunicorn.sock localhost I get
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bad Request (400)</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Bad Request (400)</h1><p></p>
</body>
</html>

And I get from browser when I input likarnet.com
This site can’t be reached
likarnet.com refused to connect.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

When I use command curl -v localhost:80 I get
* Host localhost:80 was resolved.
* IPv6: ::1
* IPv4: 127.0.0.1
*   Trying [::1]:80...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 80
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/8.5.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Server: nginx/1.24.0 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Sat, 22 Jun 2024 06:41:09 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Referrer-Policy: same-origin
< Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
< 

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bad Request (400)</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Bad Request (400)</h1><p></p>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

And the ERROR Traceback from my log file:
ERROR 2024-06-22 06:26:47,521 /home/likarnet/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py  124 Func: response_for_exception Task: None Process:  1274 MainProcess Thread:  133201422356608 MainThread Message: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'localhost'. You may need to add 'localhost' to ALLOWED_HOSTS. StackInfo: None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/likarnet/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/likarnet/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 133, in __call__
    response = self.process_request(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/likarnet/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 48, in process_request
    host = request.get_host()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/likarnet/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 162, in get_host
    raise DisallowedHost(msg)
django.core.exceptions.DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'localhost'. You may need to add 'localhost' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

I am not sure which data is also important. And I am going to add everything needed.
Thanks for your help and advice.

Your error is related to the ALLOWED_HOSTS in settings, because in your print output, ALLOWED_HOSTS is [....., ...., 'localhost'], but the error message states:
django.core.exceptions.DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header:
localhost'. You may need to add 'localhost' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

The validate_host method is called in the get_host method, and we are sure that 'localhost' exists in ALLOWED_HOSTS, but the error still occurs!!!
restart your gunicorn service and test it.It might be that you updated the ALLOWED_HOSTS after the service was started.

Could you, please, help how to do it correctly?
I do not understand how the whole system works together.
I tried restart, reboot and daemon-reload many times but stills get the same error.
I load ALLOWED_HOSTS in settings.py from environment variable, but it looks like the error appears before this parameter gets loaded.
Thank you!

@MykhayloChornenkyy, in your settings.py, after defining ALLOWED_HOSTS, print it to verify if your environment data is loaded correctly. Ensure that your ALLOWED_HOSTS variable is of type list and contains the correct hosts. Stop gunicorn service and then run gunicorn directly in the terminal to see print output.

am I doing right? I stopped gunicorn, and then used command 'gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 likarnet.wsgi' to run gunicorn manually? Right? I got printed ALLOWED_HOSTS from 'settings.py' as expected 'ALLOWED_HOSTS= ['likarnet.com', 'www.likarnet.com', '64.225.77.248', '127.0.0.1', 'localhost']'. But I am not sure that ALLOWED_HOSTS are loaded the same if I use gunicorn service. How can I be ensured? Thank you very much!

When I used 'systemctl status gunicorn' there is a row 'ALLOWED_HOSTS= ['None']'. What am I doing wrong that my ALLOWED_HOSTS are not loaded? I tried to do it from global variables and now with 'EnvironmentFile=/home/likarnet/website/likarnet/.env' in [Service]. But it still does not work. Help me, please

so you are using the EnvironmentFile but still the ALLOWED_HOSTS is empty?  If so, it might be because you didn't daemon-reload and restart gunicorn.
If you reload it and it still doesn't work( ALLOWED_HOSTS still empty ) , I suggest using django-environ.
